# Segmentation Fault when deleting an existing object

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

My code have one thread continuosly handling objects queued by other threads. Queued objects are created using "new" in a function that will have finished when the object will be handled. I have no problem with this but deleting the object.
Should I just not delete the object? Maybe change the way of passing/creating this objects?

```
Object* myQueue[10];

function() {
    Object* myobject = new Object();
    queueObject(myobject);
}

queueObject(Object* object) {
    myQueue[index_x] = object;
    sem_post(&mySemaphore);
}


//// Thread 1
function();
...

//// Thread 2
handleObjects() {
    while(true) {
        sem_wait(&mySemaphore);
        // handle myQueue[index_x]
        delete myQueue[index_x]; ---> this produces Segmentation Fault
    }
}
```

(the treatment of index_x is not posted to abbreviate)

Comment: The" treatment of index_x" may well be the important part ;) I don't see anything immediately wrong with what you've posted here.  Some possibilities: you may not be removing the Object from myQueue after deleting it (or not manipulating index_x in such a way that you don't delete Object again); index_x may be out of bounds; etc.

Comment: I can check its properties just before deleting it, so index is correct

Comment: The fact that it is valid just before deleting it suggests that another thread made index_x invalid before the address for the delete operation was computed...

Answer (score 1):

Add some checks around the delete

```
 if ( myQueue[index] != 0 ) {
      delete myQueue[index];
      myQueue[index] = 0;
 } else {
      for diagnosis print large warning here - something is confused 
 }
```

this catches double deletion via the same index. However there are several other ways a crash could occur. Catching those would need other actions.

Consider:

1. Is there any possibility of a race condition? Could two threads attempt to delete at the same index? Do you need to add any synchronization?
2. Is it possible for the same object to be added to the array twice, with different indexes? In extremis I might add code to verify that the item isn't already in the array before adding it.

Comment: If there's a race condition involving index this will still cause unexpected behavior and probably crash eventually (nulling out the wrong index will cause memory to leak, and/or get double constructed later).

Comment: Concerning race condition: yes I'm listing some ways that we could get the symptom, the null check is not solving them all. I've clarified my intention. Nulling the wrong index is the least of the problems: if the index is wrong you've just deleted the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a race condition. What is the synchronization mechanism you're using to prevent `index_x` from being modified by both threads?

Typically a worker thread should call sem_wait, modify the critical data, and then call sem_post. I can't provide 100% accurate example code without seeing how you're using index_x, but it will look something like the following:

```
queueObject(Object* object) {
    sem_wait(&mySemaphore);
    myQueue[index_x++] = object;
    sem_post(&mySemaphore);
}

handleObjects() {
    while(true) {
        sem_wait(&mySemaphore);
        // handle myQueue[index_x]
        delete myQueue[--index_x]
        sem_post(&mySemaphore);
    }
}
```

Currently it looks like you have nothing to prevent index_x from being modified by both threads, this can cause index_x to do whacky things (fail to increment or decrement being the most common whacky thing). [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing) is a wikipedia article explaining exactly what can go wrong.

Comment: I found the mistake. The problem was in the destructor. I feel stupid :(